# Regex for contains pair of words

Tags: regex

I want to find if sentence has a pair of word, for example

word = "not interested"

and should match "I am not interested" and "I am not also interested"

even though there is a extra word between `not` and `interested` I want to match it
how can I express this as regular expression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
not\s+(?:\S+\s+)?interested
```

[Regex demo.](https://regex101.com/r/A85NHv/1)

---

`not` - match `not`

`\s+` - match any amount of spaces

`(?:\S+\s+)?` - optional, match any anoumt of non-spaces + spaces (a word)

`interested` - match `interested`